# "Resolved all models on destination route, finalizing transition". But Ember renders 'view:loading'

Tags: ember.js

Router calls all hooks but hangs in `finalizing transition` then renders `view:loading`.

The problem is, I don't know why Ember isn't finalizing transition, as far as I know `models:menus` is already fetched and `categories` are sideloaded.

Both categories and categories.index routes are defined. categories and categories:index controllers are defined and are `Ember.ArrayController.extend({})`

### CategoriesRoute

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.modelFor('menus').findBy('id', params.menu_id).get('categories');
  }
});
```

### CategoriesIndexRoute

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.modelFor('categories');
  }
});
```

### What Ember logs:

https://gist.github.com/pekhee/b07917dcf6d9f78bb7d1

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of a template for controller, Ember hangs in `finalizing transition` since it can't render that template.

I'm not a 100% sure though, apparently as of Mar 2014 Ember App Kit `grunt server` task isn't compiling new files.